# Managing Azure Storage Account's lifecycle via Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm creating / managing Azure Storage Account via Terraform using azurerm_storage_account (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/storage_account.html). As I don't see it in data providers / modules list, I am wondering is it possible to manage Storage Account's blob lifecycle policy (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts) via Terraform to make the IaC experience complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not yet possible to use Terraform to handle Azure Storage Lifecycles. The feature is new (GA on March 27, 2019). I've created [an issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/3316) on the AzureRM provider to track this.

EDIT: It's now possible!

Comment: All right then. I''l be watching closely. Thanks!